# Rearranging gradients in the chain rule

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I wish to find the following 
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial g(x)}
\end{align*}
where $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$, $f,g:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$. Using the chain rule, with $y=g(x)$, as
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}
\end{align*}
So I was thinking of writing $\frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial y} = \left(\frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x}\right)/\left(\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}\right)$, but I don't think this is right because both of the terms on the right hand side are vectors. How do I rearrange terms when the terms are multi-dimensional?

Comment: I don't think this is possible. You need to be able to determine the change $\partial f(x)$ in $f$ that results from a change $\partial g(x)$. But just knowing the change in $g(x)$ does not tell you in which *direction* the change happened - it could be in any direction, with various magnitudes. So you cannot uniquely determine the change in $f$.

Comment: This honestly makes no sense. Are you trying to do implicit differentiation in higher dimensions?

Comment: @NotNotLogical Thanks, what additional information regarding $f$ and $g$ would make this possible?

Comment: @TedShifrin I suppose that's what it is. It just seems that if I know how $f(x)$ changes in $x$ and I know how $g(x)$ changes in $x$, then shouldn't I know how $f(x)$ changes with respect to changes in $g(x)$? What other information would I need?

Comment: @user131095 You would need to specify the direction in which $x$ is changing. In that case your fraction would simply equal the ratio of two directional derivatives, but I am not sure if that is what you are looking for.